# weird error when trying to install ParseUI via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I'm trying to build an App using Parse as my backend and Xcode 7.0 & Swift 2. So in order to use `PFQueryTableView`, I need to use `CocoaPods` to install `ParseUI` first. I did this and used `.xcworkspace` to re-enter the project and then tried to compile and run it. But instantly I got this very nasty error:
`ld: 823 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

These 2 lines are just the bottom 2 lines of the error messages, because there are a lot and they all start with something like:
duplicate symbol `_OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFUserFileCodingLogic in:`
or anything like that

I have many frameworks installed like Bolts, and it seems not a lot of people get this like me.

Comment: I can't , because there are A LOT, I mean hundreds of lines

Comment: But most of them look alike, saying something like duplicate symbol, and the last 2 lines are "ld: 823 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFUserFileCodingLogic in:
    /Users/xiaochenggu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseStarterProject-Swift-bykofptbjfndecbirjzgzluowers/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libParse.a(PFUserFileCodingLogic.o)
    /Users/xiaochenggu/Documents/iOSProject/parse-starter-project-1.9.0/ParseStarterProject-Swift/Parse.framework/Parse(PFUserFileCodingLogic.o)

Comment: so it seems, i linked libParse.a and Parse twice, but I don't know how to correct them

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I'd both installed Parse via Pods as well as by dragging the libraries into my Frameworks directory manually.

I removed the Pods directory and everything that said Pods from my app's build phases and it seemed to work out.